# Displaying jQuery popup on mousehover

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, mousehover

Within an ASPX page, I would like to have the popup shown within the closes xy coordinate of where mousehover is done (similar to windows status bar where when we mousehover outlook it shows something next to it. )

So in my ASPX page currently I have the jquery that shows the dialog in the center of the page (it masks the ASPX page into whole white and then displays the the actual content as a popup window) but I would like to show the popup closer to the mousehover without masking the aspx page.

The ASPX page has few jquery references. 
Below is the ASPX page.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PageScript" runat="server">
    <div class="inline">
        <a href="#" tabindex="-1" class="question-quality"></a>
        <span>Quality:</span>
    </div>

<div id="dialog_product-quality" class="dialog-content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="dialog-content-padding">
        <p>
             <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ProductQualityContentText" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<link type="text/css" href="/store/javascript/css/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery151.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('div#dialog_product-quality').dialog(dialog_options);

$('a.Quality').hover(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   openDialogWindow('div#dialog_product-quality', 'Product Quality');
});
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Please suggest.

thanks.

Comment: are you trying to pop up a new browser window, or are you using the jquery dialog class?  An example / demo would be most helpful.

Comment: Please review this:  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I have included the code. I had difficulty adding for the first time and it took sometime to put it.Please review and suggest me. thanks

Comment: There is a serious problem with what you've posted.  You've included jQuery **after** jQuery UI; jQuery **must** be included **first**, before any of its plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> ...I would like to have the popup shown within the closes xy coordinate
>   of where mousehover is done...
>
> ...The ASPX page has few jquery references...
>
> ...Please suggest.

jQuery plugin, **qTip2**, will give you the option of having the popup tooltip or modal box follow the mouse pointer, if that's what you're asking.  See mouse tracking demo below.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#mouse

[jsFiddle Demo with Code](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/v6KMr/)

[Download](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/download/) and include the qTip2 JavaScript & CSS files.

```
<div id="demo-mouse" class="box">
    <h3>Hover over this box to see mouse tracking in action</h3>
</div>


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#demo-mouse').qtip({
        content: 'I position myself at the current mouse position',
        position: {
            my: 'top left',
            target: 'mouse',
            viewport: $(window), // Keep it on-screen at all times if possible
            adjust: {
                x: 10,  y: 10
            }
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding ocassionally when tracking!
        },
        style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow'
    });
});
```

Comment: I reviewed the demo and it is exactly what I am looking for. Please suggest how to achieve the same.

Comment: @Anirudh, you'll simply need to follow the [qTip2 tutorials](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/tutorials/) for adding it to your site and configuring it to your needs.

Comment: @Anirudh, just click the "view source" button on the upper-right corner of the demo I posted to see how it was done.  I also added a link to the jsFiddle Demo.